# Hibernate: complex self join query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

How to create this query with Hibernate (with use of Specification interface / JpaSpecificationExecutor)?

```
SELECT i1.*
FROM Images AS i1 LEFT JOIN images AS i2
ON (i1.Gallery = i2.Gallery AND i1.Submitted < i2.Submitted)
WHERE i2.Submitted IS NULL;
```

Source:
https://www.exchangecore.com/blog/mysql-sql-retrieve-most-recent-or-largest-record-group/

I have tried this so far:

```
public Predicate toPredicate(final Root<GalleryEntity> root, final CriteriaQuery<?> query, final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
    final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
    final Join join = root.join("Images", JoinType.LEFT);
    join.on(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("Gallery"), join.get("Gallery")));

    predicates.add(join.getOn());


    return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
```

}

Comment: Specification has access to CRITERIA BUILDER, so making joins are possible from there. Check on that .

Comment: see my updated question: @Antoniossss

Comment: And what is generated with this snippet? Have you debug generated sql? Im not fluent with the APi so it looks ok and should work I would ionly return empty predicate as it is not required to return whats in ON clause again